# Error during booting Ubuntu 22.04 (GLib-GIO-CRITICAL)

Tags: 22.04

I see in logs after reboot

```
GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed

GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish
It seems it works normally, just this message in the log file after every reboot.

Comment: Exact same issue here. Did you have any luck fixing this ?

Comment: No, I've not fixed it.

Comment: The idea seems to be that this is a race condition at boot involving the Gnome Desktop Manager (GDM) or `gnome-shell`. I know nothing more. Still looking. Please do update your post if you advance on the issue.

Comment: Maybe related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1968907

Comment: These messages are still in the log. It has not been fixed so far. Kernel 5.17.